# How to connect separate meshes without turning it into a single mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

[image]As stated above I want to know how to connect two separate meshes but not into a single mesh. For example i want to connect the arm and hands together however i still want them to be seperate meshes and not all in one, an example of what I don't want is like ctrl + j which joins them all together.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "connect" -- maybe parent?  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html

Comment: You probably mean that you want them to be separated objects? `CTRL` + `J` joins them into one object, not exactly one mesh. And as @KickAir8p said, you should explain what you mean by *connected*.

Comment: I'm unsure on how to simplify my question even more but. Basically the game i'm making my model for requires the body to be split into multiple parts(due to limitations). What i want to do is connect the parts together but not merge them together. If i used CTRL + J for example, lets say the hand and arm mentioned early, if i use CTRL + j one of the objects like the hand will disappear and combine with the arm and therefore i can only export one mesh or bodygroup and not both. Here is the website that explains the limitations http://www.the303.org/tutorials/gold_mdl.htm

Comment: maybe use parenting for "connecting"?

Answer (score 0):

Guys i've found the answer to the question myself. What you have to do is first off select both the armature and mesh(in this case the arm in the photo). And then go into weight paint mode, select the bone in which you want to weight down and start painting around that area in my case i choose the elbow bone. Finally after painting go into your vertex groups and choose the vertex groups you assigned your bone to. There should be a lock icon next to it, press it. After that when you click and drag the elbow in pose mode the whole arm won't move but instead the elbow stretches.